# ReactJS: Set priority order of component - if field exists

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
const useItemsF = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("user")
      .where("id", "==", `${user.uid}`)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const listItemsUsers = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }));
        setItems(listItemsUsers);
        setLoading(false);
        
      });
    console.log(loading);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
  return items;
};
```

I then use the following in my return:

```
const ItemList = () => {
  const listItemF = useItemsF();
}

return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
      <a href="/dashboard"><h1><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTachometer} size="lg" /></h1></a>
        <Card elevation={3} className={classes.card}>
          <CardContent className="cardoverride">
            {listItemF?.length && listItemF[0]?.userProfilePic?.userPicURL !== 'undefined' ? <img className="dashimage" src={listItemF[0]?.userProfilePic?.userPicURL} /> : (
              <img className="dashimage" src="/Image.jpg" />
            )}
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
       </div>
    </>
);
export default App;
```

This works fine, but what I end up seeing in Image.jpg before the userProfilePic. How can I restructure this so you don't see the Image.jpg at all? So if the user has set a Profile Pic, this shows instantly (or at least does not show the Image.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

so what is happening is, the component is rendering first (at this time, `items.userProfilePik` doesnt exist, so the `/Image.jpg` is rendered). Once the comp is done rendering, then your useEffect fires, where your firebase stuff is happening, which i'm guessing fetches the profilePik from the database and sets state using `setItems`. Only now, will your `items.userProfilePik` render.

One way to solve this problem is initiate another state as such:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

//then in your useEffect
//...
setItems(listItemsUsers);
setLoading(false); //add this line
//...

//then in your return statement do something like:
return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
      <a href="/dashboard"><h1><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTachometer} size="lg" /></h1></a>
        <Card elevation={3} className={classes.card}>
          <CardContent className="cardoverride">
           { loading 
             ? <div>Loading...</div>
             : listItemF?.length && listItemF[0]?.userProfilePic?.userPicURL !== undefined 
               ? <img className="dashimage" src={listItemF[0]?.userProfilePic?.userPicURL} /> 
               : <img className="dashimage" src="/Image.jpg" /> } 
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
       </div>
    </>
);
```

Comment: Thankyou - how would I use this return as I already have the other code in my return statement? (have edited the question)

Comment: ive edited my answer to reflect how you'd use it in your return statement

Comment: Thanks - I get a loading has not been defined error...

Comment: you need to define the `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)` look again at the code i have written above. Define this `useState` statement before your `useEffect`

Comment: Still no go ... have edited question with the changes I have made as per your recommendation ... the console log only ever returns true

Comment: `console.log(loading)` is returning true, cuz the place where you are logging it, it is always true. When you fire `setLoading(false)` the component rerenders, but not the `useEffect` so you will never get `console.log(loading) === true`. try `console.log(loading)` just above your return statement. The expected behaviour should be: first time, `loading === true` and after a bit of time it should `=== false`. if that happens then solving the rest of your issue should be easy

Comment: Still shows just true

Comment: another issue i just noticed is, you are firing your `unsubscribe()` in the `useEffects`'s return statement. The `useEffect`'s return statement will fire only when the component unmounts. is that really the behaviour you want?